# how can i get full name and age in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, map-function

hello currently i learning javascript alone, i have a question!

**question**

```
let arr = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['lastName', 'Kim'],
    ['age', 40],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
];
```

**This is what I wrote**

```
function test5(arr) {
 let result =[]
  arr.map(function(ele){
    for(let i=0; i < ele.length; i++){
       if(ele[i][0]==='firstName'||ele[i][0]==='lastName'){
         result.push(ele[i][1])
       }
       if(ele[i][0]==='age'){
         result.push(ele[i][1])
       }
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

rule.

- if person have first and full name (both) then have to be combined

**i want to get value like this**
let result = [ ["Joe", 42] [" Mary Jenkins", 36] , ["Kim", 40] ]

Comment: Here's example code using objects instead of arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/23f4wxeb/

Comment: Did you write the code with the array data structure, or is that part of the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert the nested array into Array of objects and carry out object iteration

```js
let arr = [
  [
    ["firstName", "Joe"],
    ["age", 42],
    ["gender", "male"]
  ],
  [
    ["firstName", "Mary"],
    ["lastName", "Jenkins"],
    ["age", 36],
    ["gender", "female"]
  ],
  [
    ["lastName", "Kim"],
    ["age", 40],
    ["gender", "female"]
  ]
];


const createObject = a => {
  const res = {};
  for (let el of a) {
    res[el[0]] = el[1];
  }
  return res;
};

const results = [];
arr.forEach(a => {
  if (a && a.length !== 0) {
    const destructedArray = createObject(a);

    destructedArray["name"] = "";
    if (destructedArray.firstName && destructedArray.lastName) {
      destructedArray.name = `${destructedArray.firstName}, ${destructedArray.lastName}`;
    } else if (destructedArray.lastName) {
      destructedArray.name = `${destructedArray.lastName}`;
    } else {
      destructedArray.name = `${destructedArray.firstName}`;
    }
    results.push([destructedArray.name, destructedArray.age]);
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your data structure is not correct. I am assuming you have an array of objects something like this.

```
let arr = [
  {
    'firstName': 'Joe',
    'age': 42,
    'gender': 'male',
  },
  {
    'firstName': 'Mary',
    'lastName': 'Jenkins',
    'age': 36,
    'gender': 'female',
  },
  {
    'firstName': 'Kim',
    'age': 40,
    'gender': 'female',
  }
];
```

Then your test function will be like below-

```
function test5(arr) {
 let result=[];
 arr.forEach(function(elm){
  let entry={
    'name':elm['firstName'],
    'age':elm['age']
  };

  // this if will put append last name if present in elm
  if(elm['lastName']){
    entry['name']=entry['name']+' '+elm['lastName'];
  }
  result.push(entry)
 })
 return result;
}
```

You will get this result-

```
[
    {name:"Joe",age:42},
    {name:"Mary Jenkins",age:36},
    {name:"Kim",age:40},
]
```

Comment: this data structure is right haha,
that's why i'm dying